# Rust - Using map with mutable reference and async; possibly using Stream?

Tags: rust, rust-futures

Is there a way with Rust to perform the following operation without making `models` mutable? Possibly by using `Stream`? The core issue with using `uuids.iter().map(...)` appears to be (a) passing/moving `&mut conn` into the closure and (b) the fact that `DatabaseModel::load` is `async`.

```rust
// assume:
// uuid: Vec<uuid::Uuid>
// conn: &mut PgConnection from `sqlx`

let mut models = Vec::<DatabaseModel>::new();
for uuid in &uuids {
    let model = DatabaseModel::load(conn, uuid).await;
    models.extend(model);
}
//.. do immutable stuff with `models`
```

A more basic toy example without (a) and (b) above may look like the following, which is closer to what I wish for:

```rust
let models = uuids.iter().map(|uuid| DatabaseModel::load(uuid));
```

Comment: What is the problem with making `models` mutable? You can always make it immutable again after the mutable operations by doing `let models = models;`.

Comment: I'm not interested in arguments about temporary mutability, I'm simply curious if what I'm hoping for can be achieved. Though my intention is that typical fp operations are less noisy and are clearer about what they intend.

Comment: In that case, you could do it with `Stream` by wrapping your `conn` in a `RefCell`, so that you can use it in the closure, and just `.await` the `load` operation.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, what you're looking for is a [`Stream`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html), a.k.a. *"an asynchronous version of `Iterator`"*.

You can adapt an existing iterator into a stream by using [`futures::stream::iter`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/stream/fn.iter.html) and chain that with `.then()` to call an `async` function for each element. Here's an example ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fa260f117fc70c9ddefb752140caf7fd)):

```
use futures::StreamExt;

let models: Vec<_> = futures::stream::iter(&uuids)
    .then(|uuid| DatabaseModel::load(conn, uuid))
    .collect()
    .await;
```

However, this won't work if `conn` is a mutable reference. Streams can't ensure that their futures run purely sequentially. Through the stream its possible to create multiple futures, which would all need the `&mut Connection` to make progress, but that is not allowed. You would need some form of interior mutability, likely an asynchronous `Mutex`, to ensure use of `conn` is exclusive ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=166c3a6779b74ba271ebfb1127566b21)):

```
use futures::StreamExt;
use tokio::sync::Mutex;

let conn = Mutex::new(conn);
let models: Vec<_> = futures::stream::iter(&uuids)
    .then(|uuid| async {
        let mut conn = conn.lock().await;
        DatabaseModel::load(&mut conn, uuid).await
    })
    .collect()
    .await;
```

If that is unsavory, then you do need a `for`-loop with `.await` to ensure that uses of `conn` are exclusive. Since that is pretty much set in stone, any other method to create `models` without mutating it would simply be obtuse.

Comment: I should have clarified I was also hoping to avoid a Mutex. Maybe the exclusive access I'm really searching for here is a serialized queue that also holds onto the connection. It processes each closure in `.then` 1-by-1 and additionally includes `&mut conn` as an argument to the closure. Since the queue is serialized there's only 1 closure accessing conn at a time. Is there anything like that? (Reminds me somewhat of libdispatch.)